# QGIS default value form slow

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a point layer postgis with some fields that georeference the point (comune, provincia, river etc.)
I need to set these fields with a default value that appears in qgis form when I insert a point, possibly I can change them.
[image]
So I solved it introducing sone default function using refFunctions v1.0 plugin.[image]
I have used 5 functions like this.
It works fine  but after inserting the point I must wait 10 second to open the form. 
So I have the fields already filled but it's all slower.
Using postgis trigger or autofield plugin I can't see the default values in form and this doesn't help me to correct inaccuracies.

Some ideas to speed things up?

UPDATE

I'm triyng to develop a solution using QGIS field calculator in python?
Every suggestion is welcome

Comment: The 'mview_limiti_comune_vl' layer is view?

Comment: Yes, it's a materialized view to limit the size of original layer.

Comment: out of curiosity: how did you get the combo boxes in your first image? is it a new feature from QGIS 2.18 to display foreign keys? nevermind i found it

Comment: it isn't a new feature. It is a "value relation". You can choose from a list that is a field of a loaded layer

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately some of the reffunctions functions are inefficiently written and resort to fetching tons of features from the layer, resulting in this delay. I'd file a bug with the reffunction plugin itself.

Comment: Yes, it's true. So i'm trying to develop a python solution